Question about the value of $k$ in the proof of $\sqrt{\langle\mathfrak{a}^N\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle\mathfrak{a}\rangle}=\langle\mathfrak{a}\rangle$?
I have a question about the value $k$ that is from Leon Lampert's  (@leo) answer. where as part of his answer for showing $\sqrt{\langle\mathfrak{a}^N\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle\mathfrak{a}\rangle}=\langle\mathfrak{a}\rangle$, he states: $k:=k_1+\cdots+k_s-s+1$, where each $k_i=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_l\}$ for counding $m_i=x_{j_1}^{a_1}\cdots x_{j_l}^{a_l}$.  But should't $k={k_1+\cdots+k_s+s-1\choose s-1}$ for the following reasons, if we let each of the $k_i=\star$ and each of the $m_i=\;|\;|$,  there there are $s$ number of $k_i$s consider to be indistinguishable, and they need to be placed in $s-1$ number of boxes, or equivalently, $s$ number of $\star$s and $\;|\;|$s bars in accordance to Sammy Black's answer here?
Thank you in advance.
